# Android XDK Intel Html5 - img src width file:///storage/sdcard0 does't work

Tags: android, html, image

if I tag a link on img src put file directly: file:///storage/sdcard0/myimg/test.jpg, so the image in the Preview are view but in Android Build compilation appears not.

```
<img src="file:///storage/sdcard0/myimg/test.jpg">
```

Its correctly in App Preview.  Not view with Android ?

Why? Do I need to use a different path?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

I installed the new version (Sep 2014) of XDK.
In this version, let the android.config.xml files to edit and expand itself.

I put the Permission "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE".

Now the images are displayed.